# Why is my insertion sort algorithm altering numbers in the given array? (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, insertion-sort

I have a C++n insertion sort function template, and it works fine when I give the function an array of integers, but when I give the function an array of doubles, although the array is indeed sorted afterwards, for some reason it alters the numbers in the sorted array.

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void insertionSort(T ary[10], int size)
{   
    // Printing unsorted array
    cout << "Array before sorting: [";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << ary[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    // Beginning of sorting
    int j, t;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            j = i;

            while(j > 0 && ary[j] < ary[j-1])
            {
                t = ary[j];
                ary[j] = ary[j-1];
                ary[j-1] = t;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    // Printing sorted array
    cout << "Array after sorting: [" ;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << ary[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "]\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "*** INTEGER ARRAY INSERTION SORT ***" << endl;
    int intAry[10] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i<= 9; i++)
    {
        intAry[i] = rand() % 100;        
    }

    insertionSort(intAry, 10);

    cout << "*** DOUBLE ARRAY INSERTION SORT ***" << endl;
    double dAry[10] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        dAry[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 100;
    }

    insertionSort(dAry, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

**The output:**

[image]

You can see here that it changes the number in the array of doubles, like 14.1603 to 14.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Because `t` is declared as `int`. It should be of type `T`.

Comment: `int j, t;` is wrong. `t` needs to be `double` when the array elements are `double`, so `int j;` and then `T t;`. Also, your nested `for` loops use the same index name (`i`) - very dodgy.

Comment: The variable "t" inside the insertion function is of type int. When you assign a double to it, it rounds down. Change it to be type T and you should be good.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Good point about the nested `for` loops. I don't think the outermost loop is even needed, is it?

Comment: Unrelated, unfortunately your insertion sort is guaranteed O(n^2) comparisons worst case, and it needn't be. The descending linear scan of the already-sorted sequence to establish the resting place of the next element in question (which you incorporated with a swap-down operation to save the extra loop) can/should be done with binary-search instead, then shift (which you're currently doing anyway as part of your inner loop).  In short, you can significantly reduce your comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you want to compare the double numbers, but when you're going through the loop, you use the int i and int j variables. Result is incorrect due to incompatible data type.
if you covert "double" the "int" data types, your problem will be solved.

Also you must change your array type to double.